# Valuing Bonds With Continuous Coupon Yields

Tags: finance

How do I find the value of bonds with continuous coupon yields and interest rates that are both a function of time?

Comment: This isn't really a math question. Have you tried https://quant.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I didn't know about it, thanks for telling I will ask this question there.